# Is there any platform other than Huggingface, heroku or streamlit share to deploy a streamlit application?

Tags: python-3.x, deployment, streamlit

I have a python streamlit code and CSV files of about 35GB and I'm creating a docker image which is about 2.5GB. Is there any Hosting  Service or Platform where I could deploy the streamlit application along with the CSV files?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deploy Streamlit apps on [most hosting services](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/streamlit-deployment-guide-wiki/5099), including AWS, Azure, GCP, Digital Ocean, and Google Colab.